# JS multiple scopes between files

Tags: javascript, module, scope, global

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812159/595305) shows how to share a scope across several JS files.

But I'm wondering how one might go about having two (or more) levels of wider scope, shared between multiple files.

Experimenting, I've found that a slight tweak to the above answer involves sharing an object between files, and then initiating it the first time it is found to be an empty object like so:

```
var MODULE = (function( widerScopeVariables )
{
    if( $.isEmptyObject( widerScopeVariables ) ){
        // projectWide:
        widerScopeVariables[ 0 ] = {};
        // formsWide:
        widerScopeVariables[ 1 ] = {};
    }
    const projectWide = widerScopeVariables[ 0 ];
    ...
```

... but the trouble is that `projectWide` and `formsWide` (intended to be of more restricted scope) are then both available to every file sharing this `MODULE` variable, even if by convention you restrict use by files which aren't intended to have access to the `formsWide` variables.

Furthermore, every file which might be the first to load has to include the above code.

Is there a better way to accomplish this sort of multi-level multi-file scoping in JS?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "multi-level global scope". There's only one scope level that can be global.

Comment: @Bergi whoops, you're right... I shall now edit accordingly...

Comment: I still feel you are confusing "variables" with "properties". A scope is not an object. And no, apart from the global scope, no variables can be shared between multiple files.

Comment: @Bergi look at the answer I referenced... you'll understand a bit more.

Comment: That answer talks about modules - objects. Not scopes. The revealing module pattern scope cannot be shared across files, only the exported values can be through putting them on a global variable.

Comment: Splitting hairs.  The task, then, as I think you are in fact aware, is to mimic scope which is wider than individual functions but narrower than true JS global variables.

Comment: No, they're completely different things. You cannot mimic scope - local ("private") variables - with (possibly nested namespace) module objects whose properties are always public.

Comment: I disagree... and as you clearly aren't capable of understanding this simple but useful requirement, let alone providing a solution, I suggest you stop cluttering up this question with unhelpful and rather patronising remarks about things I already know.  You're not helping.

Comment: Well if you are not capable to explain with proper terminology what you mean by "levels of wider scope", we cannot help you to achieve that goal. But to answer your question: **No**, there is no other way than to share objects - possibly even nested ones for "namespacing" - and it's not possible to restrict access other than by convention (though of course you can build a module loader system that checks these conventions).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a sort of way to help accomplish this. It's not elegant, and merely encourages the right kind of use... it will not please JS purists, but it works for me.

For the avoidance of doubt I am aware that JS has only two scopes: global and function.

What I have done is to put a bunch of files in a subdirectory called "generic_elements".  Using the design pattern in the answer I referenced I then go like this in these files:

```
var HOLDER = (function( holderState )
{
  const genericDir = getDir( -2 );
  const genericWide = holderState[ genericDir ] = holderState[ genericDir ] || {};
  ...
  return holderState;
}( HOLDER || {} ));
```

where `getDir` looks like this (global function):

```
function getDir( pathElement ){
    let info = new Error().stack;
    const infoLines = info.replace( /\n/g, ' ' ).split( ' ' );
    const delimiter = '/';
    // [0] or [1] would return the line for this file, not the calling file
    const tokens = infoLines[ 2 ].split(delimiter);
    // get a directory in this path. -2 means penultimate token = string between penultimate and last '/'
    return tokens.slice( pathElement )[ 0 ];
}
```

... it's not the "full" version in that it only returns the final directory rather than the complete path from the main URL directory.

The idea is pretty simple: a bunch of files in a subdirectory use the path of the subdirectory containing these "files in a module" as a key in the `holderState` object.  They share the object `genericWide`.  Modules higher up can still look at this `HOLDER` object, but coders (hopefully) agree not to use key-value pairs from modules they know nothing about. Conversely, files in subdirectories **will** be able to work out the paths of ancestor directories, calling `getDir` with -3 or -4 or whatever... so they will be able to access their ancestor modules' "directory-wide" objects.

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend to hardcode the module/directory names and not rely on the nonstandard and fragile `Error().stack` property for such a fundamental functionality.