# How to break down a .js file into different files like PHP's include (or require) so that I don't have to use namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an `app.js` main file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

var multer = require('multer')
var path = require('path')  

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Do something 
})

app.get('/api/get_entities', function (req, res) {
    // Do something else
})
```

How can I break this down into different files. Maybe something like:

**main_imports.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

**do_this.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
```

**this_too.js**

```
app.get('/api/get_entities', function (req, res) {
    // Do something else
})
```

**all_app.js**

```
main_imports.js
do_this.js  
this_too.js
```

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

I am looking for something that can work something alike **PHP** `include` (or `require`) so that I don't have to use namespaces.

I would like the final file to be a dump of all functions, and not have to do:

```
var do_this = require('./do_this');
console.log(typeof do_this.foo);
```

and instead just have:

**all_app.js** finally having:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

var multer = require('multer')
var path = require('path')  

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Do something 
})

app.get('/api/get_entities', function (req, res) {
    // Do something else
})
```

Comment: umm, have you checked [export and include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)?

Comment: you can check [multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752627/how-can-i-split-a-javascript-application-into-multiple-files)

Comment: I am looking for something that can work something alike **PHP** `include` (or `require`) so that I don't have to use namespaces.

Comment: you are currently using `require` or I get something wrong?

Comment: are you using an automation tool like grunt or gulp? you can concatenate these files into one with uglifyjs.

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/app.js','utf8',(err,data)=>{
        cuts=data.split('\n'); //split the data w.r.t line breaks and store in an array


        })
```

Now the contents of the js file are stored in an array. Get the index of the points which you want to include in your file. Then-

```
 fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/main_imports.js',cuts.splice(0,x));
```

Where x is the index of the last line or your file.
Repeat this process for all the files you want to create. This can be done in a loop also, but you want all file names to be different so manually.